# How Refresh Table component onChange Event

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have react component in which I am showing data in the table, also have **Select / dropdown**. The table and `select` are in same component. I need to refresh table component soon the value change in the dropdown. My implementation does refresh the table and call API but there is delay when that happened. I am not sure if I have implemented correctly?

the idea is `eziSearchCriteria` is in `useState` and `onChange` event I am assign value to it.

```
const MyComponent = () => {

 const[eziSearchCriteria, setEziSearchCriteria] = useState<IEziStatusSearchCriteriaForm>();

  const eziSitesStatusCovers = [

    { label: 'UNSCHEDULED', value: 'UNSCHEDULED' },
    { label: 'COVERED', value: 'COVERED' },
    { label: 'PART COVERED', value: 'PART COVERED' }, 
  ];


   useEffect(() =>{
    setInitialPageLoad(true);
    setDefaultSearchCriteria();
  },[]);

   const handleSearchFilter = (event) =>{
    if(event!=null){
    eziSearchCriteria.coverStatus = event.value;
    setEziSearchCriteria(eziSearchCriteria);
   }
 }

 return (
  
 <div>
  <div className="searchFilter">
    <Select 
      options={eziSitesStatusCovers}
      onChange = {handleSearchFilter}
    />
  </div>

     { eziSearchCriteria ? (
      
      <TableItems
      url={url}
      apiUrl ={api.eziTrackerStatus}
      columns={columns}
      customParams= {eziSearchCriteria}
      key={eziSearchCriteria.coverStatus}
    ></TableItems> ) : null} 

    </div>
   );
  };
```

....

```
 export interface IEziStatusSearchCriteriaForm{
   startTime: string,
   endTime: string,
   scheduleId?: number,
   coverStatus: string
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and answer.

I was changing one value in the object `eziSearchCriteria` but object is same/ reference variable and react state not considering to render on this change. I created new object and assign to `eziSearchCriteria` and it worked straight away.

```
const handleSearchFilter = (event) =>{

if(event!=null){
   eziSearchCriteria.coverStatus = event.value;

 var searchCriteria2 : IEziStatusSearchCriteriaForm = {
  startTime: "12-08-2020",  //MM:DD:YYYY
  endTime: "12-09-2020",
  schedAction_Active: "Active",
  coverStatus: event.value
 }

     setEziSearchCriteria(searchCriteria2);
 }
}
```